# Python-docx. Конвертируем .docx в .txt

Tags: python, производительность, docx

Здравствуйте, уважаемые участники сообщества. Хотел бы задать вам вопрос по теме одной из сторонних библиотек, а именно python-docx. Суть заключается в том, что  требуется взять .docx файл и сконвертировать в .txt, но как бы я ни старался сделать это, 160кб файл .docx конвертируется 4.5 минуты. Возможно я что-то делаю не так, не уверен. В моей задаче файл состоит из одной, многостраничной таблицы и я просто беру, циклом пробегаюсь по всем строкам таблицы, сохраняя каждую ячейку в файл, примерно вот так:

```
rowses = []
for table in document.tables:
    rowses += table.rows
for row in rowses:
    s = ""
    for cl in row.cells:
        s += cl.text
        s += " "
    text_file.write(s + '\n')
```

Но этот алгоритм работает уж сильно долго, знаете ли вы другие, более быстрые способы? или возможно, я что-то делаю не так... Надеюсь на вашу помощь, спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это старая проблема с docx - [github issue](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/174). Все плохо из-за того, что как-то очень криво извлекаются ячейки из массива с ячейками.

В качестве обхода можно потыркать потрошки библиотеки:

```
from docx import Document

doc = Document("doc.docx")
text_getter = lambda cell: cell.text

for table in doc.tables:
    CELLS = table._cells
    column_count = table._column_count
    for row in table.rows:
        row_index = row._tr.tr_idx
        print("Номер строки: ", row_index)
        text_row = CELLS[row_index * column_count: (row_index + 1) * column_count]

        print(' '.join(map(text_getter, text_row)))
```

Вы не привели примеров таблиц, поэтому я тестировал на самой простой - создал большую, но очень простую десятистраничную таблицу и запустил (на всякий случай - ссылка на файл: [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zq8qo87nllyvfc3/doc.docx?dl=0)). Время работы отличается разительно - как видите, я залез в защищенные поля и использовал иначе, чем в библиотеке. Вот пример того, как обрабатываются ячейки для таблицы в библиотеке:

```
@property
    def _cells(self):
        """
        A sequence of |_Cell| objects, one for each cell of the layout grid.
        If the table contains a span, one or more |_Cell| object references
        are repeated.
        """
        col_count = self._column_count
        cells = []
        for tc in self._tbl.iter_tcs():
            for grid_span_idx in range(tc.grid_span):
                if tc.vMerge == ST_Merge.CONTINUE:
                    cells.append(cells[-col_count])
                elif grid_span_idx > 0:
                    cells.append(cells[-1])
                else:
                    cells.append(_Cell(tc, self))
        return cells
```

Как видно, **каждый** раз, когда вы извлекаете текст из ячейки, эти самые ячейки читаются из файла заново. Все ячейки из всей таблицы - крайнее расточительство. Альтернативно можно просто считать ячейки один раз и сохранить их в массив, что и было сделано мной в примере - ячейки читаются один раз и сохраняются в `CELLS`.

Comment: Замечательный ответ! Спасибо большое